# US-Michigan Can I use two ground terminal bars in a sub panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm finishing the electrical rough-in on a 100 amp subpanel for a new workshop.  I have unbonded the neutral, and run two ground rods on 6AWG bare copper and also have a ground conductor coming from the main panel.  I'm wondering, is it OK to use two ground terminal bars in the sub panel for the sake of making wiring easier / neater? (One on either side.)  If so, should I run a conductor between the bars?

The reasoning is, this particular cabinet has plug on neutrals which go the vertical height of the panel.  It makes it very convenient to run all of a drop to near the same place, but if there's only one ground bar and it's on the other side of the panel, I end up having to run the ground all around the panel to the other side, making it tougher to keep it neat.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, that's no problem.  Just make sure the ground bar is actually grounded.

Comment: Make sure the neutral is isolated from ground since this is a sub panel, if adding bars I usually will run a jumper as an extra layer of security.

Answer (score 1):

You can put in as many as you want.  Just scrape the paint off under them and bolt them down tight.  (See Above)